# Digital Signature Tab in .exe of the desktop project

Tags: digital-signature

I have an `.net` desktop application, I want to sign application like `messenger` and `skype.exe`.

The below dialog box is takin by the properties of skype messenger..

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhI8n.png

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to formulate your question besides describing what you want.

You need to buy code signing certificate from one of certificate authorities (we use GlobalSign as their certificate can be used for driver signing) and sign your compiled application using signtool (included in Windows and .NET development kits).

Comment: thank you very much for ur responce...
actually i hav sample certificate and i include it throygh project->properties->signing 
but when i take properties of project's .exe file,digital signature tab doesnot show...

Comment: @user987147 try signing with signtool